# Embedding a Site into Facebook as an Application

Tags: facebook

Do I required to build my website using a particular language for me to embed it in Facebook App? I have a gaming site. If I want to embed it in Facebook, what do I modify?

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to promote your site on facebook, rather than adding functionality to facebook itself, you should probably start with a [Facebook Page](http://www.facebook.com/advertising/?pages).  This gives you a fair amount of tools and ways to interact with facebook users, without needing to write a facebook application.  If you then decide you need an app, you can create one in addition to your page.

If you decide you need an application, you can (broadly speaking) use any language to write it, as your app will need to be hosted on your own web server.

A good place to start your first app is here:

- http://developers.facebook.com/get_started.php

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to modify anything in your site. You can embed your site in fb using their iframe applications settings. To create your app, you need to go to following url and then put your sites url in the iframe.

www.facebook.com/developers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to modify your site but application should have another view and behaviour. It's like two sites with same data. For example, check the difference
http://game-land.appspot.com/ - gaming site
http://apps.facebook.com/gamelands/ - facebook application of this site